# How to delete a struct in c programming which has member functions in the following struct?

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

i am able to create all the functions below and performed all the operations as well but i am unable to delete this tree, so please someone help me how can i delete the struct which is of this type

```
typedef struct Tree
{

Node *root;

Data *(*insert)(struct Tree *, Data);

Data *(*search)(struct Tree *bst, Data value);

void (*sort)(struct Tree *, Data *);

int (*compare)(struct Tree *t, struct Tree *copy);

struct Tree * (*clone)(struct Tree *t);

void (*delete)(struct Tree * bst);

void (*removeData)(struct Tree * bst, Data value);
}Tree;
```

Tree Instance is as below

```
Tree *newTree()
{

    Tree *bsttemp = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));

    bsttemp->root = NULL;

    bsttemp->insert = &insert;

    bsttemp->search = &search;

    bsttemp->sort = &sort;

    bsttemp->compare = &compare;

    bsttemp->clone = &clone;

  //  bsttemp->delete = &delete;

    bsttemp->removeData = &removeData;

    return bsttemp;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show how you're creating the `Tree` instance. It makes a difference in how it gets destroyed.

Comment: Isn’t this just a definition?

Comment: After malloc struct Tree, you can just free the pointer. If some pointer in `struct Tree` also set by malloc，then you need free these pointer too. For funtion pointer, it normally point to functions, which not come from malloc, so no need free.

Comment: structs don't have member functions.

Comment: @user1118321 below is the tree instance                                                                       Tree *newTree()
{

    Tree *bsttemp = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    
    bsttemp->root = NULL;
    
    bsttemp->insert = &insert;
    
    bsttemp->search = &search;
    
    bsttemp->sort = &sort;
    
    bsttemp->compare = &compare;
    
    bsttemp->clone = &clone;
    
  //  bsttemp->delete = &delete;
    
    bsttemp->removeData = &removeData;

    return bsttemp;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is at least uncommon to put functions in a C struct. As C will not automatically pass a `this` pointer, you will have to use something like

```
struct Tree *tree;
...
struct Tree *tree2 = tree->clone(tree);  // same as directly calling: clone(tree)
```

It is normally only used to implement *virtual* functions meaning here that the function can depend on the object, which is a **very** uncommon use case - it normally depends on a group of objects and because of that the object only has a pointer to a vTable which is kind of an array of functions.

That being said in C the rule is: first destroy members, then free the object, so here if could be more or less

```
void delete(Tree &tree) {
    // destroy and free descendants of root
    ...
    // destroy and free root
    ...
    free(tree);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to emulate classes in C....

Anyhow,

```
Tree *bsttemp = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
```

Whoever gets the bsttemp pointer (caller of your newTree() function) can simply call free() on that pointer.

BTW, don't cast malloc(). It is unnecessary and can hide errors in pre C99 versions of C.